# Is this proof of union closed set conjecture verified?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I have always found [union closed conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture) very interesting. There is an [arxiv article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01270) claiming the solve the problem. My background is not appropriate to read the proof. Is this proof verified or wrong? Any comment would be appreciated.

The article was submitted in 2015 and it is not too long(about ten pages). Thus, I expect that it should be verified until now.

Comment: In this question (closed) there was a rather painful discussion on a different paper by Vladimir Blinovsky, he himself also participated as Mikhail http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176538/is-the-manickam-miklós-singhi-conjecture-solved/176563#176563

Comment: Identical question one year ago (but with no answers): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765189

Comment: My first reaction to this question, upon looking at the paper: "Well, it's just a ten page paper. Why not just check it?". And then I scrolled down to the second page and horrified, closed the paper.

Comment: Vladimir Blinovsky also recently posted a 3 page proof of the Riemann Hypothesis on the arXiv https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03827

Comment: There will be  12 pages soon with detailed proof - this is just the sckech

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its asking for the correctness of a preprint claiming to prove an open conjecture. Further, this question was used to try to justify asking about a RH claimed proof, which is clearly off-topic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a recent [thesis](https://repositorio-aberto.up.pt/bitstream/10216/87152/2/158981.pdf) by André da Cruz Carvalho on this conjecture. It discusses the paper by Vladimir Blinovsky and shows why his proof does not work (page 16). NB: I have not read it carefully, and this refers to the first version of Blinovsky's paper.

Comment: Has anyone checked if the criticism still applies to the current and 7th version of the paper?

Comment: I checked - not applies V.Blinovsky  :)

Comment: There's now an 8th version of the paper